# How to run commands from containers that has USER set in the dockerfile without encoutering and permission errors

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I just started using docker recently. I have written a Dockerfile for a django app as shown below. I created and set the user. However anytime i try to **run or exec** a command in the container defined in my docker-compose.yml (web) I get a permission error.  **gunicorn project.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000** give similar error. How to I resolve this permission errors. Any help will be much appreciated. I have the dockerfile and the compose defined below. Thanks in advance.

```
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine

ENV APP_USER=user
ENV APP_HOME=/code
RUN addgroup -S $APP_USER && adduser -S $APP_USER -G $APP_USER

# set work directory
RUN mkdir -p $APP_HOME
RUN mkdir -p $APP_HOME/static

# where the code lives
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install pillow dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk --no-cache add g++ \
    && apk add gcc python3-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev libmagic

# install dependencies
# copy project
COPY . $APP_HOME
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


# chown all the files to the app user
RUN chown -R $APP_USER:$APP_USER $APP_HOME

# change to the app user
USER $APP_USER
```

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: sh -c "python ${APP_HOME}/manage.py makemigrations &&
      python ${APP_HOME}/manage.py migrate &&
      python ${APP_HOME}/manage.py runserver  0.0.0.0:${APP_PORT}"
    volumes:
      - .:${APP_HOME}
      - static_volume:${APP_HOME}/static
    ports:
      - ${APP_PORT}:${APP_PORT}
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    restart: "on-failure"

volumes:
  static_volume:
```

Comment: Your `volumes:` are overwriting all of the code in the image.  Can you delete that block from the `docker-compose.yml` file?  A Python virtual environment might be a better match for a local development setup.

Comment: when remove  - .:${APP_HOME} it works but that removes the mapping to the working directory

Comment: Yes, it does.  You'll use the isolated reusable copy of the application built into the image.